# Custom Class Sprite kit

Tags: swift, xcode, class, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm trying to give my main character a Custom Class so that I can define all his behaviors inside the defined class.

I already did something like this, by using protocols:

```
protocol CustomNodeEvents{
    func didMoveToScene()
}
```

This protocol is in the GameScene file, before the class starts.
Then I call the function like this in the GameScene class:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

if let customnode = player as? CustomNodeEvents{
       customnode.didMoveToScene()
   }
}
```

Where the player is defined as:

```
player = self.childNode(withName: "//player") as! SKSpriteNode
```

also inside the didMove(to view: SKView) function.

Now I created another file (my custom class file) and I write:

```
import SpriteKit

class Custom: SKSpriteNode, CustomNodeEvents{
    func didMoveToScene() {
         print("It Worked")
    }
}
```

I don't have any errors but it doesn't actually run the block of code inside my Custom class (in the GameScene.sks file I already attached the class to the player).

My question is how can I make it work?
And the second question is, is this the best way to define a Custom Class and "connect" it with other classes?

EDIT:

---

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var player: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    player = self.childNode(withName: "//player") as! SKSpriteNode

    if let customnode = player as? CustomNodeEvents{
       customnode.didMoveToScene()
    }
```

Comment: hmm,  did you typo the protocol?  you have CustomNodeEvents(), should it have () on it?

Comment: also, it looks to me that player may be a SKSpriteNode, not a Custom, so in your "if let"  you are getting a failed condition, skipping over the didMoveToScene

Comment: I would double check the SKS file to make sure that player has custom class defined as Custom, then do `player = self.childNode(withName: "//player") as! Custom`.  If this fails, then we know where the problem is

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it was just I typo, edited! As I said it runs without any errors. I also thought about the second comment, I'm trying to figure out what's missing, since it worked before the update (at least this process worked, not necessarily the example I wrote)

Comment: When you write condition code the way you are doing, try evaluating your need of it. If you need to guarantee that a player has to exist, then unwrap the optional or provide an "else" condition. Leaving the if like that without a safe guard just makes debugging a pain, and will yield in undesirable results when it is in production.  Last thing you want is for it to break on your customers, and they have no way of explaining how it broke.

Comment: I tried to unwrap the player as Custom and I have no errors, but it still doesn't run the function. I'm interested in the unwrapping story, can you maybe write an answer with an example so that I know what you mean with the else statement ... ?

Comment: `if let customnode = player as? CustomNodeEvents{
       customnode.didMoveToScene()
   }
} else { print("Error casting customnode")}`  You could also use `assert` so that it crashes on the correct line

Comment: wait,  where do you define player?  You may be setting it AFTER you call `didMove( to view)`

Comment: I got it, thanks for clearing this part, now I'm still thinking of how to use the protocols, or even if there's a better way

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Edited to show declaration and definition

Comment: I did exactly your code, and it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where the problem is, but this code works for me:

```
import SpriteKit
protocol CustomNodeEvents
{
    func didMoveToScene()
}
class Custom : SKSpriteNode,CustomNodeEvents
{
    func didMoveToScene()
    {
        print("It Worked")
    }
}


class GameScene:SKScene{

    var player : SKSpriteNode!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        player = self.childNode(withName: "//player") as! SKSpriteNode
        if let customnode = player as? CustomNodeEvents
        {
            customnode.didMoveToScene()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error creating node")
        }
    }

}
```

I can only conclude that there is an issue in the sks file, and the player we are grabbing is not the player you are looking for, or the player is not of class Custom.  (Note I placed the player sprite at the top most level of the scene)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm really confused, it could be that the update of xcode doesn't print me the string, because it runs without errors but nothing is printed

Comment: everything prints and works as expected for me,  make a new project, replace gamescene with my code, go to the sks file, go to the media library tab on the bottom right, drag in a spaceship, name the sprite, give it the custom class, save the scene, and run.  You will see it works

Comment: It has worked, thanks a lot! But this is weird since it seems that the problem was using a `color sprite` instead of an image. I just noticed that it says "error creating node", but I can still access the player and change it's position when I choose a color sprite. What could the problem be ?

Comment: That means you are not getting a custom class,  you are getting a sprite node

Comment: This makes me think it's a bug of xcode, that doesn't save when I give a colored sprite a custom class

Comment: the bug is 100% you buddy, it works on color nodes for me.  Make sure you are hitting ENTER when you finish typing a name.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it did not save the state of the object when I press ENTER. It's not the first time it doesn't save the state of an object after changing it. I just learned to save manually the file everytime to be completely sure :/

Comment: it does save it every time, I have had zero problems with the editor,  if you are in a text edit mode, and you leave the tab, everything reverts,  that should be expected

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are casting `player` as a `SpriteNode` and then later trying to upcast it to a `CustomNodeEvents` protocol.  Assuming your sprite custom class is set in the `.sks` file as you say, SpriteKit should be creating an instance of your custom class so you can just do:

```
if let customNode = self.childNode(withName: "//player") as! Custom {
   customNode.didMoveToScene()
}
```

Comment: Mmh I think I'm understanding, in fact I declared the player at the beginning as:

Comment: var player: SKSpriteNode!

Comment: @jlyonsmith, you are going against the protocol logic though.  What if player is no longer Custom, but some other class?

Comment: (Sorry for the multiple comments) The point is that I want to make an `update` function inside the Custom class at the end. And doing this searching for the player every time would cost a lot!